# Example of a meromorphic function with no analytic continuation outside the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

The bottom line of the ["Analytic Continuation" page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnalyticContinuation.html) on WolframMathWorld states:

> there exists a meromorphic function  in the unit disk where every point on the unit circle is a limit point of the set of poles.

I must admit that I've been rather surprised by such a statement, therefore I tried to construct this example by myself and to google for it, but nothing came up. Do you have any idea on how such a function looks like?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case you missed it: A link on your cited page points to a construction on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalBoundary.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually did miss it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 53 [here](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~statmath/stinc/database/notes/CASolutions.pdf) says that if $$B(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{|a_n|\over a_n}{a_n-z\over1-\overline{a_n}z}$$ with $0<|a_n|<1$ and $\sum(1-|a_n|)<\infty$ then $B(z)$ is a holomorphic function on the disk with zeros precisely at the points $a_n$, $n=1,2,\dots$. The $a_n$ can be chosen so that every point of the unit circle is a limit point.

It would seem that the reciprocal would do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I was looking for! I'm going to do the exercise then!